# mysql user last login / access date time

Tags: mysql, linux, mysqladmin, mysqladministrator

During in a audit task, I am going to delete few mysql users. Before delete I want to check, when the last time these user access the database server.
I want to know if we have this information stored in *information_schema* or *mysql* databases. If not how can we achieve this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno: How does that policy apply here?

Comment: He is just asking for a solution, plus he didn't provide his tries, plus the question is unclear and broad

Comment: @MarcoSalerno: There are vote-to-close options for "Too Broad" or for questions seeking debugging help without providing code.  But those aren't the ones you quoted.  How is this question asking for recommendations for off-site resources, as you indicated?  The OP is asking for information, but is not asking for recommendations for any particular tool.

Comment: He is asking for a solution without providing code as i said, we aren't a tutorial website ^^

Comment: The debugging flag is for other circumstances

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I can't provide my tries and code in this case. I tried and search solution for this but when I can't find a solution, I posted a question here.I agree it is not a  tutorial website.

Comment: @FaizanYounus: Unless there are records of login events in an audit log somewhere, I'm not seeing any tables which directly store the last login for a database user.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look in the general log for any unsuccessful connection attempts to MySQL however out-of-the-box, MySQL typically does not log successful DB connections.
This could become a very, very large log and that activity may quickly overwhelm the I/O subsystem and cause problems for the DB.

You can setup this sort of logging however it will result in quite a LOT of data!
have a look at this post over in the DBA Exchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/668/audit-logins-on-mysql-database

If you are using a DB server that is yours and yours alone, you should be able to do this. If you have a DBaaS type thing, multi-tenant DB systems would die logging each connect. This may not be possible?

You may also find some steps on enabling usertracking in MySQL from the Percona blog: https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/12/28/auditing-login-attempts-in-mysql/

Comment: One does not need to log each connection, just the timestamp of the most recent connection.